# Invalid Default Value for MYSQL Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using the Geospatial extension for MySQL. In the `MyISAM` table `listings` there is a `GEOMETRY` column `p`, and 2 `float` columns `lat` and `lng`. Values in `p` are set using `UPDATE listings SET p = POINT(lat, lng);`.

**Problem:** Now I want to set a spatial index on column `p`. When I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE listings ADD SPATIAL INDEX(p);
```

and also tried:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON listings (p);
```

Both times, I get the error `error : All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL`.

So (using Navicat) I tried making col `p` `NOT NULL`, but it requires a default value. What default value should I use for this? I tried using `''` as the default value but it gave an error `invalid default value for 'p'`.

I tried setting the default value for `p` as `POINT(0,0)` but I get the error `BLOB/TEXT column 'p' can't have a default value`

How should I approach this problem to create the spatial index? Thanks!

### Edit

After running query `ALTER TABLE listings CHANGE p p POINT NOT NULL`, running `ADD SPATIAL INDEX(p)` causes a strange error `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. Other queries that does not involve creating an index works fine ie. `SELECT * FROM listings`

**Results from `SHOW CREATE TABLE listings`**

```
CREATE TABLE `listings` (
 `listing_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `website_city` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `website` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `price_per_br` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bedroom` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bathroom` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fee` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `postal` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `retrival_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `post_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p` point NOT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `img_subpath` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `photos` text,
 `reply_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_dishwasher` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_laundry` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_fireplace` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_elevator` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_balcony` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_deck` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_backyard` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_parking` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_gym` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_pool` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `cats_ok` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dogs_ok` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`listing_id`),
 KEY `lat lng` (`lat`,`lng`,`price`,`price_per_br`,`bedroom`,`bathroom`,`post_timestamp`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `spatial` (`p`(25))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=589605 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I converted `p` to back to `GEOMETRY`, ran the query to add the index to `p` and got a new error `Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`

Comment: AFAIK you don't have to have a `DEFAULT` for a column. It might be that Navicat is trying to add extras to `ALTER TABLE`. Did you try to run `ALTER TABLE listings CHANGE p p POINT NOT NULL;`?

Comment: I tried `ALTER TABLE listings CHANGE p p POINT NOT NULL;` and the query was successful. But when I tried to create the index now, after just a few seconds I get the error ` Lost connection to MySQL server during query` using both Navicat and PHPMyAdmin... hmmm

Comment: Does that happen for every query or just when you try to create the spatial index?

Comment: Just when creating the index. `SELECT * FROM listings` work fine.

Comment: What happens when you run `ALTER TABLE listings CHANGE p p POINT NOT NULL, ADD SPATIAL INDEX(p);`?

Comment: Same error: `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. My SQL version is 5.1.61cll using `SELECT version();`.

Comment: that's probably just plain timeout.. do it again.

Comment: Can you run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE listings` and add the output in your question? I fear the column `p` is not `GEOMETRY` but `TEXT`.

Comment: @ypercube Updated original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page [InformIT: Data Types in MySQL](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1238838&seqNum=2) claims that spatial columns cannot have a `DEFAULT` value but I can't locate that info in MySQL docs:

> **3.2.3 Specifying Column Default Values**
>
> For all but BLOB and TEXT types, spatial types, or columns with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, you can specify a DEFAULT def_value clause to indicate that ...

Testing in my 5.1 box shows the same error as yours. So the claim is probably correct.

Comment: What do you think I should try to get a spatial index on the `POINT` column `p`? Should I upgrade to 5.5?

Comment: Updated to MySQL 5.5.21cll and I get the same error when trying to add the index.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.

It is not possible to set a Geo-Datatype as DEFAULT value. But you can use triggers:

1. Define your table as followed:

   ALTER TABLE Node ADD latlonGeo POINT NOT NULL;
2. Create a trigger to set the "NOT NULL"-column:

   CREATE TRIGGER default_geo_column 
   BEFORE INSERT ON Node 
   FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.latlonGeo = GeomFromText('POINT(0 -999)');

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick !

```
ALTER TABLE `devices` ADD `last_location` POINT;
UPDATE `devices` SET `last_location` = ST_GeomFromText("POINT(0 0)");
ALTER TABLE `devices` MODIFY `last_location` POINT NOT NULL;
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX `location_index` ON `devices` (`last_location`);
```